# MongoDB: How to know if MongoDB consists specific document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

For example i have collection (`Posts`) and i want to know, if my Posts consist some document, example:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

Posts.insert({
  name: "John",
  ....etc.
)};

var TMP = {
  name: "John",
  ....etc.
};
```

I want to know if my Posts have some document that "equal" TMP

How i can do this **???**

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but wouldn't Posts.findOne() do it? You could even pass in Posts.findOne(TMP)

Answer (score 0):

This will check for a document with all the keys/values in the TMP object.  It will return undefined if there is no matching document.

I put the following code in the server folder somewhere:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");

var postExists;

var TMP = {
  name : "John",
  age: 26
};

// postExists should return undefined when TMP is not in the collection
//  !!postExists will evaluate to false
postExists = Posts.findOne(TMP);
console.log("When doc doesn't exists, postExists = " + postExists);

Posts.insert(TMP);

// postExists will return the object when if it does exists
// !!postExists will evaluate to truew
postExists = Posts.findOne(TMP);
console.log("When doc does exist, postExists = " + postExists);
```

Comment: It's return undefined !

Comment: Which evaluates to false.

Comment: I write in //do something `console.log("YES")` and it's not log this (i haven't got TMP in Mongo, Mongo is reset)

Comment: The //do something will only run if the TMP IS in mongo

Comment: it's  return undefind every time if i have got TMP or NOT in my Mongo

Comment: in [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) it's must return TRUE or FALSE

Comment: Where are you running this code, server or client?  I would run this code  on the server first (in a JS file somewhere in the server folder) to make sure it works. After that you'll need to make sure your subscriptions are set up properly on the client

Comment: I run it on server, maybe you can try do it and tell me your result in `postExists`